# Copy and Paste GWT ListBox Value

Tags: gwt

we have a GWT ListBox and at the moment we are applying some validations to make ListBox Disable BUT the problem is we can't copy its selected value to paste some where else.

Please can you suggest the best approach to implement this?

Comment: what do you need to implement exactly? Please be a little more specific about the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, this is one of those convienince methods still missing; though I'm not sure if there is a reason.

You will have to get the selected index and then use that to get the associated value. This can be done whether the ListBox is enabled or disabled.

Here it is in one line:

```
String mySelectedValue = myListBox.getValue(myListBox.getSelectedIndex());
```

Here is the documentation: https://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ListBox.html

You can the add this wherever you need it. The easiest is with classes that implement the HasText interface.

Here is an example using a Label:

```
myLabel.setText(mySelectedValue);
```

Here is the documentation: https://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/HasText.html

Hope that helps.